# Java server-client model

Tags: java, model, client-server

This question is more concerned with the general design of a program. I have a problem in hand in which a centre communicates with a set of clients individually (the clients do not directly interact with each other).

The content of the communication between the centre and a client is entirely numeric, i.e. a bunch of numbers are sent back and forth. The clients are run on individual computers, and the centre can be hosted on another machine (or otherwise). The style of communication is iterative and synchronous in a sense that the centre sends a request/question msg to each individual client and the user of a client provides an answer/reply back to the centre within a time limit in each iteration, and this interaction repeats itself for a number of times until the end.

The centre does some calculation given the responses received from the clients, and the clients simply provide the inputs to that calculation.

I wonder what is an elegant design for this problem using Java? Any comment or suggestion is much appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: What factors prevent you from keeping it simple -- some basic TCP/IP communication? Are you looking to reuse existing libraries? Trying to communicate with a very large number of clients? Are you interested in the discovery of the server address aspect? Fault-tolerance? What is most important -- efficient resource usage / latency / throughput?

Comment: Is it necessary that the center starts the communication? A server has usually a service, which is called by clients. How you describe your architecture, turns your clients to servers (they have to listen for requests) and your center to a client.

Comment: @Dilum Ranatunga: i actually would like to keep it as simple as possible given the context of the application. The number of clients is not large at all - up to 10 clients will be connected to the server at a time. Could you please elaborate more on the TCP/IP implementation?

Comment: @Puce: maybe I should clarify that the centre does not invoke any service programmed on a client. It's more like that the centre asks a question (derived by an algorithm) which is sent to a client and the client replies an answer provided by an user who uses the client to interact with the centre.

Comment: What you describe is still one kind of a service: a client (here the center) asks a question, which is sent to the server (here a client). The server (here a client) listens for incoming questions and provides a response. The "listening" part turns the client to a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [KryoNet](http://code.google.com/p/kryonet/) which can efficiently serialise your datasets over RMI invocations (remote method calls). Using it myself, and it works well. Has UDP and TCP without any mucking about. Start from the example on the site and work from there. You can easily get both sides of the connection working with RMI.

Comment: Hi Chris, I have taken a look at KryoNet. It looks promising, however the simplistic examples on its front page is rather basic in illustrating its functionalities. In particular, I wonder how a KryoNet-based server can handle (and also being able to identify) multiple connected clients. Identification is key here as the server may behave differently for different clients. Thanks.

Comment: The identification would be initiated by the server holding a login object with OID of 0 which the clients would connect to. The clients would call the login method on the server with the required role. If success, in this login function the server would create an object which allows the client to interact with the server and would store this and return an object containing the interactive object information (server object ID, client object ID). The client and server's objects would be customised depending on the client type.

Comment: So effectively, the server identifies an client using an object (created by the server) with which the client interacts? Can I assume that such objects behave differently according to interacting clients? But what is the purpose of the second object 'containing the interactive object information (server object ID, client object ID)'? Could you give a short example please? Thanks.

Comment: The server has an oid counter which it increments, which it stores and uses as its own ID. The counter is incremented again to generate the client oid. Both oids are sent, and the client adopts the given oid as its object, while storing the server object oid. Both IDs need to be registered appropriately on both ends on sending from server and receiving by the client. Depending on the remote connection info, the type of the remote object can be ascertained on both client and server. You should use a 'getRemoteClass(Connection c)' function or similar in the class which can be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds the [MPI](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/) is right for you. Here is a [Java version](http://www.hpjava.org/mpiJava.html).

Good luck and Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution in pure Java is probably to use RMI. Just expose an object via RMI and have the clients call methods on it remotely.

If you want asynchronous behavior, you can use a JMS implementation or roll you own using sockets and TCP/IP as mentioned above.

If you don't like any of those, the MPI mentioned above may be for you. Or possibly [Apache Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) may be for you.